# What is production

Tags: philosophy-of-economics, economics

In ecological economics production means "process of transformation energy/matter into another energy/matter".

So What is production in philosophy ?

Comment: Production is production.

Comment: See Aristotle ( theoria / praxis / poièsis) - Marx - Hannah Arendt ( labor / work) - Heidegger ( about technique, about art also )

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/baudrillard/#EarlWritSystObjeMirrProd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Hylemorphic model (Arisotle) : production is information of a matter, that is embodying a form into some matter, in such aa way that matter is actualized ( passes from potentiality to actuality) ; example a statue is pruduced when the form " image/ representation of a god" is given to a stone ( = matter)
- Mechanistic model ( Descartes) : production is operating a change in geometrical properties of matter ; displacing, separating, uniting, changing shape, size.
- Philosophers have established various distinctions regardng production

(1) natural production / intentional ( intelligent) production  --> Aristotle, Kant ( causing / doing, causare / facere)

(2) routine / skilled production , experience / art --> Aristotle, Metaphysics , Alpha

(3) production applying knowledge ( technique) / hability, power, art   ---> Kant, Critique of Judgment

(4) interested production (labour) / free disinterested esthetic  production   (art) --> Kant, Critique of Judgment

(5) production as labour / production as work --> Hannah Arendt, Human Condition

(6) production as transformation / production as creation ( production ex nihilo)

Maybe interesting for you : https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1086026607313580

Also : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CNXoUjqWlU&list=PLKVcO3co5aCBv0m0fAjoOy1U4mOs_Y8QM&index=2&t=0s